# Center img over another img without moving

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```css
.logo {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}

.logo img:last-child {
    position:absolute;
    right:40%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
</div>
```

I want to put the second image over the first one. But when I resize the size of the screen, the image who is over the first moves
. I want it to be fixed and not moving.

Thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 2):

You should use like this -

**Update-**

and you need to add -

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

--

```css
img{
  max-width:100%;
}


.logo {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}

.logo img:last-child {
     position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
</div>
```

Comment: See by yourself how it works jsfiddle.net/guksqd5p/1

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if you put a static width on `.logo` it will stay where it is above the img. Otherwise this will just center it even if `.logo` changes its width.

```css
.logo {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}

.logo img:last-child {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying it on jsfiddle, When I resize for mobile size it moves

Comment: @CorentinBranquet, how does it move? With this code it stays center in the container div (even on resize).

Comment: See by yourself how it works, when you resize the result section jsfiddle.net/guksqd5p/1

Comment: @CorentinBranquet, with a static width it will stay inplace. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg6yjdph/)

Answer (score 1):

Let me know. You may have to add this to both classes and use z-index to stack them on top of each other.

```
.logo img:last-child {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logo {
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    
}

.logo img:last-child {
    position:absolute;
    right:40%;
    top:0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250">
</div>
```

Comment: Its because you want to put 40% from right. If you allow equal space or in px, I can fix it